# How to show resized sidebar using SWRevealViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SWRevealViewController in IOS app (universal). I'm getting sidebar in iPhone and iPad both but I want to show sidebar which covers 90% of screen - how can I?

Comment: it always covered the 90% of the View , can u show the screen shot which type u need

Answer (score 13, accepted):

open the `SWRevealViewController.m` file and then u get the `_initDefaultProperties` Method. in this method you get the side screen size and position

```
- (void)_initDefaultProperties
{
_frontViewPosition = FrontViewPositionLeft;
_rearViewPosition = FrontViewPositionLeft;
_rightViewPosition = FrontViewPositionLeft;
_rearViewRevealWidth = 260.0f;      /// this is the method u change the side bar width
_rearViewRevealOverdraw = 60.0f;
_rearViewRevealDisplacement = 40.0f;
_rightViewRevealWidth = 260.0f;
_rightViewRevealOverdraw = 60.0f;
_rightViewRevealDisplacement = 40.0f;
_bounceBackOnOverdraw = YES;
_bounceBackOnLeftOverdraw = YES;
_stableDragOnOverdraw = NO;
_stableDragOnLeftOverdraw = NO;
_presentFrontViewHierarchically = NO;
_quickFlickVelocity = 250.0f;
_toggleAnimationDuration = 0.25;
_frontViewShadowRadius = 2.5f;
_frontViewShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.5f);
_frontViewShadowOpacity = 1.0f;
_userInteractionStore = YES;
_animationQueue = [NSMutableArray array];
_draggableBorderWidth = 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: customize your self ,

Comment: thank you .. 
but what if i need to do it run time means i will determine the device type and according to that i will display the size of the sidebar... @Anbu.Kartik

Comment: @PremalKhetani - device type means iPhone and iPad

Comment: @Anbu.Kartik yes either iphone or ipad i have to show side bar accordingly without changing in library (SWRevealViewController).

Comment: yes i know that but what if i want to do it manually, means i have requirement that have to show....

Comment: For iPad there is UISplitViewController so you dose not requires a SWRevealViewController for that.Search google for UISplitView.

Comment: I am showing the slide menu on click of a particular button,but can I use the same button for a split view controller in case of device being iPad?

Answer (score 2):

Just have an if statement to determine the correct size of the sidebar. something like this:

```
if(device == iPad)
     _rearViewRevealWidth = 600.0f;
else if(device == iPhone)
     _rearViewRevealWidth = 260.0f;
```

Comment: yes i tried it but i want to use it from may front view controller not in SWRevealViewController class.

Answer (score 1):

open the `SWRevealViewController.m` file and then you get the  `_initDefaultProperties` Method.

```
 - (void)_initDefaultProperties
{

 AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

      float x=(appDelegate.windowWidth)*9/10; //windowWidth=self.window.bounds.size.width;
      float y=x-260;

    _frontViewPosition = FrontViewPositionLeft;
    _rearViewPosition = FrontViewPositionRightMost;
    _rightViewPosition = FrontViewPositionLeft;
    _rearViewRevealWidth = x;
    _rearViewRevealOverdraw = 60.0f+y;
    _rearViewRevealDisplacement = 40.0f+y;
....
}
```

Comment: if you're using the SWRevealController pod, it might be better to define this value elsewhere instead of editing the pod code. In the controller that is the revealViewController's frontView, set the rearViewRevealWidth:

            if self.revealViewController() != nil {
            self.revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.size.width * 0.80
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this... 
When you have subclass from SWRevealViewController...
call property for this problem and set as you want... 
Hope it's help someone...

```
self.rightViewRevealWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.9;
```