# Menuviewcontroller in SwRevealview slide menu not allign in center

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using SwRevealViewController for slidemenu in Objective c.
In MenuViewController.m file i am using one uiview which look like below storyboad
[image]

But in simulater it looks like below. i.e it doest not appear in center.
Whereas my contraints for uilabel and uiimagesview in horizontally center allign.
[image]

Comment: you need to set your side view width - revaltogglewidth

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik revealtogglewidth will not give me the center allignment of my tableviewcontroller i guess. please explain

Answer (score 1):

over ride the frame in **willLayoutSubviews** of your `MenuViewController`,customize ur self

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

      [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width - self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealWidth , self.view.frame.size.height)];

}
```

Comment: you get the SWL default property from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175982/how-to-show-resized-sidebar-using-swrevealviewcontroller/25176222#25176222)

Comment: @Anubu Thank you for the answer. I did it and it works for me.But the problem is when i try to drag menu more with the finger gesture it stays with the width = _rearViewRevealWidth

Comment: i want something when user drag the view and it increase ints width it always show the label and image in the center

Comment: @iosdeveloper - happy to hear, then do onething manually set the width, it willl be fine for pan and click, else i m not worked that scenario so u i cant say the excat answer, check and customize once

Comment: Thank you for the help. will check by customizing it